# Magento infinity scroll and SEO Layered Navigation extensions conflicts

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento

I have installed two magento extensions: Magento infinity ajax scroll and SEO Layered Navigation. Each of them works perfectly when the second extension not installed, but when them intalled both, magento infinity ajax scroll not working (When i scroll down, there is magento infinity ajax scrol loader appeared, but then nothing products loaded).
Is anybody solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Basically it means 2 modules rewrites the same classes (toolbar, product list block). Run some conflict checking tools to see them all

Simple solution is to install 2 modules - layered navigation and ajax scroll- from the same vendor.

Comment: Is there any other solution to resolved this problem while using Amasty's Scroll module with other vendor's Layered Navigation module?